# Android can't compress a recycled Bitmap

Tags: android, url, bitmap

I'm getting an image from a URL, I want to compress it and save it in the external memory device. I get this **error**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>           Can't compress a recycled bitmap
>           at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:400)
>           at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1307)

at this line

```
 mIcon11.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
```

---

```
String foto = UT_drive_dropbox.AM.getfoto();
Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(foto).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(mIcon11.getWidth(),
            mIcon11.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = Color.RED;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, mIcon11.getWidth(), mIcon11.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mIcon11, rect, rect, paint);

    mIcon11.recycle();


    String fileName = "avatar.jpg";
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     mIcon11.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

    File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getString(R.string.app_name) + File.separator + fileName);

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        sd.createNewFile();
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sd);
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is "Can't compress a recycled bitmap". If you look three lines before your `mIcon11.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);` line, you will see:

```
mIcon11.recycle();
```

So, either get rid of `recycle()` or move it to *after* you have done *everything* that you intend to do with the `Bitmap` pointed to by `mIcon11`.

Comment: Just to add onto this, `recycle()` should only be called when you are done with the object. Calling it in the middle of with the object is 100% wrong, it's akin to drinking a beverage, throwing it in the recycling bin half way through and then wondering why you can no longer drink the beverage.